# Dropdown button isn't centering

Tags: html, css

Somehow my dropdown button isn't aligning in center when using the custom html in Clickfunnels. I'm not really that into coding maybe someone here could help me with it.

I already tried to add different text-aligns also with !important left, right, margins etc. but it would save me a lot of headaches if it would just always easily be centered.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Centered Navigation Menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">ÜBER UNS</button>
            <style>
                /* Dropdown Button */

                .dropbtn {
                    position: relative;
                    background: transparent;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 20px;
                    width: 150px;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    border: none;
                    font-weight: 900;
                    font-family: LATO;
                    transition: ease-in-out 0.8s;
                    left: 50% !important;
                    right: auto !important;
                    text-align: center !important;
                    transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important;
                }

                .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                    background: white;
                    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
                    color: black;
                }

                /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

                .dropdown {
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;
                }

                /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

                .dropdown-content {
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 150px;
                    left: -999em;
                }

                .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                    background-color: white;
                    left: 0;
                    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
                    ;
                }

                .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                    display: block;
                }

                /* Links inside the dropdown */

                .dropdown-content a {
                    color: black;
                    padding: 12px 16px;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: center;
                }

            </style>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">GALERIE</a>
                <a href="#">LAGE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any CSS for centering your dropdown menu.

Comment: honestly i'm not sure... I copied this code from css school and edited some parts with other youtube videos.. Could you tell me which part would be needed for it to center? thanks..

Comment: You can't just copy code like that :P. I would need to know about the parent element and what else is around the drop down btn to properly position it, but in any case, I'll try to write up an answer for you. I'm not 100% sure if you can just copy/paste it since I don't know enough about your site.

Comment: It's centered for me in Chrome. What browser are you using? When I say it's centered, I mean that the menu items are center aligned with each other.

Comment: I think Christian meant centered to the entire width of the page, right? That's actually a good question to ask haha.

Comment: I'm so sorry haha. I'm not into coding at all really.. So the thing is i have a Column in Clickfunnels with like a "header" and on clickfunnels is a custom html element which i put into the column and put the code i have up there into it. the thing is, that the Dropdown button isn't in the center of this column it's left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
<head>
<title> Centered Navigation Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">ÜBER UNS
  </button>
  <style>
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    position: relative;
  background: white;
  color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 900;
   font-family: LATO;
   transition: ease-in-out 0.8s;
   left: 50% !important;
  right: auto !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  transform: translate(300%, 0) !important;
  
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
    
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    left:-999em;
 
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    left: 0;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown-menu-center {
  left: 50% !important;
  right: auto !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  transform: translate(350%, 0) !important;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-center">
 
    <a href="#">GALERIE</a>
    <a href="#">LAGE</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Please run code it will center your drop down button
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Made the changes to following 2 classes:

.dropbtn {
    position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 900;
   font-family: LATO;
   transition: ease-in-out 0.8s;
  text-align: center !important;

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you yes the dropdown is now in the center only problem now is, that the dropdown isn't a dropdown anymore so it shows all the submenu's. I will answer the question with the updated code and the trouble now. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

To center the elements inside your `div class="dropdown">`, style it with `display: block;` and `text-align: center;`

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Centered Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<style>
    .dropdown {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ÜBER UNS
        </button>

        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">GALERIE</a>
            <a href="#">LAGE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey thank you this worked but the dropdown menu now is on the left while the button is centered :(

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> Centered Navigation Menu</title>
<style>
    .dropdown {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">ÜBER UNS
  </button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">GALERIE</a>
    <a href="#">LAGE</a>
  </div>
  <style>
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 900;
   font-family: LATO;
   transition: ease-in-out 0.8s;
  text-align: center !important;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background: white;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;
    color: black;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  
}
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    background-color:white;
    left: 0;
    transition: background ease-in-out 0.5s;;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p34Cy.png)